# Adding xUnit.NET ASP.NET MVC unit tests to an existing project/solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, unit-testing, xunit.net

I downloaded xUnit.NET today, along with TestDriven.NET, and installed the ASP.NET MVC unit test templates. I have an existing ASP.NET MVC solution that I want to add an xUnit unit test project to, but it seems that the only way to create such a project is with the "Create Unit Tests?" dialog that appears when you first create an ASP.NET MVC project.

**Is it possible to add xUnit tests to an existing ASP.NET MVC project/solution?**

Comment: 9 years later. Still no support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Why cant you just add a new test project manually?   All dialog does is set up some initial tests that are pretty meaningless once you actually start coding.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll do, and then I'll just make another ASP.NET MVC project to see what the xUnit templates have.

Comment: Why not just have the option in the dialog by default?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like xunit are [removing](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9802) the templates soon anyhows - they certainly didn't work when I tried to create a new web + test project.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Did you try below?
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/06/30/an-introduction-to-the-xunit-net-testing-framework-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx

Comment: I've looked at that. Figure 3 is what I want to accomplish, **but I already have an existing ASP.NET MVC project**. So far, this only seems possible when creating a new project!